# xpath returns two buttons

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath

xpath expression `$x("//button[text() = 'Got it']")` in Chrome returns two button elements but there is only one such button in the page.

Both elements look identical, in terms of data.
Clicking on second element of the array using selenium and python sometime works but many times returns `Element is not interactable` error.

Any pointers?

`<button class="button slim-large" ng-click="ctrl.closeDialog()">Got it</button>`

[image]
[image]

Added this code to handle situation of duplicate button where one is visible and other is not.

```
    button_clicked = False
    elems = self.find_all_by_xpath(locator="//button[contains(text(),'Got it')]")
    for elem in elems:
        if elem.is_displayed():
           elem.click()
           button_clicked = True

    if button_clicked == False:
       print("None of " + str(len(elems)) + " buttons are click-able")
```

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: Please share your web url.

Comment: _there is only one such button in the page_ Are you basing this on the visual appearance of the page in the browser, or on the actual html source?

Comment: @Winner Sorry I cannot share web url

Comment: @NarendraR Here is the markup.  `<button class="button slim-large" ng-click="ctrl.closeDialog()">Got it</button>`

Comment: What about this one `//button[text() = 'Got it'][@class='button slim-large']` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon Not from visual appearance. When I hover/click over those two element in  Javascript console, browser highlights same button.

Comment: Have you tried that xpath in DevTool Elements tab? Do you see 1 of 1 or 1 of 2 in the search result?

Comment: `//div[@class='control last']/button[text() = 'Got it'][@class='button slim-large']`

Comment: Can you share the full HTML source?

Comment: @JohnGordon You were right! I removed the modal div that had visible "Got It" button and ran the xpath again and now only one button was returned!  Modified code to handle the situation. Update question.  Please convert your comment to answer.

Comment: You can add the answer and mark as answered. that way it will show as "Answered" in StackOverflow

Comment: @NaveenChandar Sure, but wanted JohnGordon to get credit first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment from @JohnJordan.
There were indeed two buttons on the page and one was hidden.
Wish developers could use unique IDs for all elements.

I removed the modal div that had visible "Got It" button and ran the xpath again and now only one button was returned! Which means there is one more hidden button in the DoM.

Modified code to handle the situation.

```
button_clicked = False
elems = self.find_all_by_xpath(locator="//button[contains(text(),'Got it')]")
for elem in elems:
    if elem.is_displayed():
       elem.click()
       button_clicked = True

if button_clicked == False:
   print("None of " + str(len(elems)) + " buttons are click-able")
```